# Google search: Define what to search in website title vs. body?

Tags: google-search, search-engine

When Google searching:

Is there a way to specify what to search in website titles vs. website bodies?

- Include or exclude certain things in the title.
- Include or exclude certain things in the body.

Is there a way to do that?

---

> Here's a hypothetical scenario:
>
> I want to find things that are *similar* to `x`, but not the same as `x`. There are probably
> websites that have lists of things that are similar to `x`. Or at
> least websites that indirectly mention `x`, which might be helpful.
>
> If I google the word `x`, I'll just get pages that are 100% about `x`,
> which isn't what I want. And when I google the category that I'm
> thinking of, I get crappy/generic results.
>
> I'd rather google for pages where `y` is in the title of the webpage (and possibly *exclude* `x` from the title), but also search where
> the page body contains `x`. (If the page contains `x`, then I'll *know*
> the website is good.)

Comment: You can use [advanced search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Google Search Operators: The Complete List (42 Advanced Operators)](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/), to find a word in the title, you use the operator `intitle`.

> **intitle:**
>
> Find pages with a certain word (or words) in the title. For this example, any results containing the word “apple” in the URL will be returned.
>
> Example: inurl:apple

To find two or more words in the title, you use `allintitle`.

> **allintitle:**
>
> Similar to “intitle,” but only results containing all of the specified words in the title tag will be returned.
>
> Example: allinurl:apple iphone

To find a word in a page body, you use `intext`.

> **intext:**
>
> Find pages containing a certain word (or words) somewhere in the content. For this example, any results containing the word “apple” in the page content will be returned.
>
> Example: intext:apple

To find two or more words in a page body, you use `allintext`.

> **allintext:**
>
> Similar to “intext,” but only results containing all of the specified words somewhere on the page will be returned.
>
> Example: allintext:apple iphone

Comment: Thanks! I Can't seem to find a way to exclude a word from the title, but include the word in body. `intitle:-maxvar intext:maxvar`

Comment: @User1973 Try: `-intitle:maxvar intext:maxvar`

Comment: Yes. That solved it. Thanks very much for your help.